# Changing the typeface from the official style in a conference paper

Tags: paper-submission, formatting

I'm a big fan of the [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_typeface) typeface for mathematical typesetting, especially compared with the standard Latin Modern. I feel somewhat justified in changing to Euler for a paper, but Euler doesn't usually look very good with the default body text typeface.

It's a small thing to change that as well (\usepackage{charter}, for instance), but at that point you're really messing with the official style supplied by the conference.

On the other hand, some conferences also allow submissions from Word documents, so the visual unity is unlikely to be maintained anyway.

So, two questions:

- How unusual and frowned-upon is it to change the math typeface?
- How unusual and frowned-upon is it to also change the body text typeface?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general you are not supposed to make any such changes. Most journals and proceedings have some form of either "instructions for authors" or template, or both, which you are supposed to follow. If you submit something with a different type face, the most likely result is that it will be changed to whatever the journal/equivalent requires.

If you submit to a conference which do not have any specifications on paper formatting, I doubt that anyone will make complaints about your formatting.

The key point I would make is: if there is a set of instructions/template which you are supposed to follow/use, then you should do so. Otherwise trust your instincts and experience of what consitutes good formatting.

Comment: As a Graphic/Copy Editor I can confirm: If the authors strongly insisted on a style change that is against the journal style, their sumbission would likely be withdrawn.